# Why are physical diseases listed under icd10?

Tags: icd-intrntl-classif-disea

I’m researching a condition called multiple chemical sensitivities.  The who do not recognise it as a physical disease.  Some countries do not recognise it as a physical disease but others do eg Germany and japan recognise it as a physical disease. Japan uses the code icd10. T65.

Having googled it seems icd10 is a classification used for mental health disorders. What I don’t get is if Japan recognise it as a physical disease why t65 which stands for toxic injury why is it listed as icd10 t65 as I believe the former is mental health.

Please clarify

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ICD-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10) is the "International Statistical Classification of Diseases and Related Health Problems"; it is **not** limited to mental health and is used for medical records, statistical, and billing purposes across the whole gamut that may cause someone to have an interaction with medical services of some sort.

The "F##" designations cover "Mental and behavioural disorders" and "G##" cover "Diseases of the nervous system" which can be a bit of a hybrid; the rest are primarily physical.